# Create a front user register/login/profile & logout without interfering with wp-login.php?

Tags: users

I need to create a register and login link on my home page.
Users get to take a quiz on their profile which they can update and what gets posted to a database.

How can I do this without interfering with the wp-login?
All needs to be done on the front end.

Comment: Please rework your question. It's quite unclear what you want and you got plenty of typos...

Comment: Yes, it's unclear! Do you want another "login", then go and create one with php. If not, @richbai90's Answer ist the right one!

Answer (score 1):

As for the custom login/registration piece, there are tons of pre-made plugins out there just for this.  Here's just [one example](http://wordpress.org/plugins/s8-custom-login-and-registration/)

If you want to develop your own there's plenty of beginner how to's all over google on the subject.

Again here is [just one](http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/)

As for the quiz piece I'm not sure what you mean, would you mind clarifying?